# Таблицы html css. Косая черта в ячейке таблицы

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте!Я даже вопрос не могу задать правильно:) Но я попробую сформулировать. Смотрите, есть таблица. На скриншоте показана косая черта в ячейке, как ее сделать?
http://myscreenshot.info/i/0003/761021382124481890271404161985.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать её картинкой и поставить на фон ячейки